# persistence and Hibernate errors in spring boot JPA

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

```
persistenceUnit/Hibernate
         Connection to persistenceUnit/Hibernate failed
         Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times
```

I have this error and when i go to jpa console and run commands, i get this:

```
access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Despite, i can see my database in database tab in intellij. And also it created entityclass.

So, why do i have those errors?

It did not create persistance.xml so i created it and put to src/web-inf

```
<persistence-unit name="persistenceUnit">
    <class>models.MovieEntity</class>
    <properties>
        <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql"/>
        <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.user"/>
        <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.password"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password"/>
        <property name="openjpa.ConnectionURL" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql"/>
        <property name="openjpa.ConnectionDriverName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="openjpa.ConnectionUserName"/>
        <property name="openjpa.ConnectionPassword"/>
        <property name="toplink.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql"/>
        <property name="toplink.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="toplink.jdbc.user"/>
        <property name="toplink.jdbc.password"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

it generated those lines but sone of them are red, errors. SAme password for all for example?

Also, i get those errors:

```
ava.lang.RuntimeException: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity: com.models.MovieEntity
     at org.hibernate.cfg.InheritanceState.determineDefaultAccessType(InheritanceState.java:277)
     at org.hibernate.cfg.InheritanceState.getElementsToProcess(InheritanceState.java:224)
     at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:775)
     at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processAnnotatedClassesQueue(Configuration.java:3845)
     at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processMetadata(Configuration.java:3799)
     at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1412)
     at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1846)
     at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:857)
     at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:850)
```

my entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "movie", schema = "mysql", catalog = "")
public class MovieEntity {
    private int id;
    private String title;
    private String actors;

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "id")
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name = "Title")
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "Actors")
    public String getActors() {
        return actors;
    }

    public void setActors(String actors) {
        this.actors = actors;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        MovieEntity that = (MovieEntity) o;

        if (id != that.id) return false;
        if (title != null ? !title.equals(that.title) : that.title != null) return false;
        if (actors != null ? !actors.equals(that.actors) : that.actors != null) return false;

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = id;
        result = 31 * result + (title != null ? title.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (actors != null ? actors.hashCode() : 0);
        return result;
    }
}
```

entity class gives error of no catalog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seen the your configuration I can see that you have the username and password empty, now probably the persistance.xml that you are posted was a example bat one of your error `access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)` follow me to advice you to check if your database was configured with a password and use it (I'm not crazy in a standard installation without configuration on linux many times I had empty password).  Then I can see that you have @Id on title properties when probably the your sql for tabel generation, requires that id was the primary key.

I hope that this can help you

Comment: i need a tutorial to follow becayse i use intellj. and i cant make it work. for example i add hibernate config file to resources byt then jpa file inside metainf-resources disappear. when i add it, hibernate disappears. I cant make it work. i use jpa console and other console but both are not working. in my persistance file there are lots of username password, i dont use all ot them.

Comment: you can take ispiration from a my open source projects link: https://github.com/mrFlick72/socialDocumentLibrary/tree/master/user-documentlibrary-client. In this project I use Spring-data but basically with spring boot yu can use the applicatio,properties for put hear the configuraton in practis you can configure all datasource configuration in application.properties / application.yml and remove the your persistance.xml

Comment: but i cant see from there for example while starting , i choose spring initializr to create pom file, is it nice? and then adding jpa and hibernate from modules .

Answer (score 0):

- The database seems to be missing in the connection string
- Most likely your Entity has no field annotated with @Id

Comment: i pıut my entity but there is @id. is not it?

Answer (score 0):

Your actual error is :

```
No identifier specified for entity: com.models.MovieEntity
```

You must specify an id in  `com.models.MovieEntity` class

```
@javax.persistence.Id
private Long id;
```

Comment: private int id; i have this. i put my code. can you look